# Validating an attribute inside JsonArray using restassured

Tags: json, rest-assured

I have a json like below

```
{
"hasErrorResponse": "false",
"responseObject": [{
    "success": true,
    "errorMessage": null,
    "availablity": "YES",
    "errorCode": null,
    "availableQtys": 1234,
    "prId": "451667"
}]
```

}

Now using `RestAssured` if I do

```
response.then().assertThat().body("responseObject.prId", equalTo("451667"));
```

It's failing because it says `Expected: 451667 but Got: [451667]`

I guess it's because it's getting the `prId` attribute as an `ArrayList` and not as `String`. How do I go about validating this sceanrio?

Answer (score 0):

`hasItems` matcher works to validate anything inside collection